# Mistake in identiy $a \cdot \sin(bx)+c \cdot \cos(bx) = A \cdot \sin(B+Cx)$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find values $A, B, C$, such that:

$a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = A \cdot \sin(B+Cx), \quad\quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}/\{0\}$

but i am missing a factor, here's my calculation:

---

#### The Amplitude A

I calculated the amplitude by finding a local extrema:

$f(x) = a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) \\
f'(x) = ab\cdot \cos(bx)-cb\cdot \sin(bx) \stackrel{!}{=} 0 \\
ab\cdot \cos(bx) = cb\cdot \sin(bx) \\
\frac{a}{c} = \tan(bx)\\
x = \frac{1}{b} \tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{c})$

Plugging this back into $f(x)$ simplifies nicely, when using following identities:

$ \sin(\tan^{-1}(x)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}, \quad\quad \cos(\tan^{-1}(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \quad\quad$:

$f\bigg(\frac{1}{b} \tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{c})\bigg)=a\cdot \sin\bigg(b \cdot \frac{1}{b} \tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{c})\bigg)+c\cdot \cos\bigg(b \cdot \frac{1}{b} \tan^{-1}(\frac{a} {c})\bigg) = \\
a\cdot \sin\bigg(\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{c})\bigg)+c\cdot \cos\bigg(\tan^{-1}(\frac{a} {c})\bigg) = \\
a\cdot \frac{\frac{a}{c}}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{c})^2}} + c\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{c})^2}} = \frac{\frac{a^2}{c}+c}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{c})^2}} = \frac{a^2+c^2}{c \cdot \sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{c})^2}} = A$

---

#### The Phase B

I just set $ x = 0$ to obtain $B$ :

$a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = A \cdot \sin(B+Cx) \\
c = A \cdot \sin(B) \\
B = \sin^{-1}(cA^{-1}) = \sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{c^2}{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{1+\big(\frac{a}{c})^2}\bigg)$

---

#### The Frequency C

Using the addition theorem,

$a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = A \cdot \sin(B+Cx) = A \cdot (\sin(B)\cos(Cx) + \cos(B)\sin(Cx)) = \\$

plugging in $B$,

$= A \cdot (\sin(\sin^{-1}(cA^{-1}))\cos(Cx) + \cos(\sin^{-1}(cA^{-1}))\sin(Cx)) = \\$

and using following identity $\cos(\sin^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$,

$= A\bigg(cA^{-1}\cos(Cx)+ \sqrt{1-(cA^{-1})^2}\sin(Cx)\bigg) =  c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ \sqrt{A^2-c^2} \cdot \sin(Cx) = \\
c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ \sqrt{\frac{(a^2+c^2)^2}{c^2(1+\frac{a^2}{c^2})}-c^2} \cdot \sin(Cx) = 
c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ \sqrt{\frac{(a^2+c^2)^2}{(a^2+c^2)}-c^2} \cdot \sin(Cx) = 
c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ a \cdot \sin(Cx)$

So now we have:

$a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ a \cdot \sin(Cx)$

I thought I can conclude from this that $b = C$, but I was wrong.

---

#### The Missing Factor

When I plot

$f(x) = a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx)$

and

$g(x) = A \cdot \sin(B+Cx)$

with the calculated values

$A = \frac{a^2+c^2}{c \cdot \sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{c})^2}}, \quad\quad  B = \sin^{-1}(cA^{-1}), \quad\quad C=b$

The two functions only overlap when the parameters $a$ and $c$ have the same sign.

[image: Picture of Geogebra file, without the correcting factor, the functions mirror each other around the y axis.]

After a few tries I figured out that it works for all values if I adjust $C$ to:

$C = \operatorname{sgn}(a) \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(c) \cdot b$

I have looked at this for hours but I can't figure out, where in my calculation I missed the $\operatorname{sgn}(a)\operatorname{sgn}(c)$ or why it should be there in the first place.

I suspect that it has something to do with the phase $B$ since the two functions mirror each other along the y axis, when $\operatorname{sgn}(a) \neq \operatorname{sgn}(c)$ and without the correcting factor.

I also tried plugging in $ C = -b $ in the frequency equation, in order to end up with the factor, but I only got a contradiction:

$
a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = c\cdot \cos(Cx)+ a \cdot \sin(Cx) \\
a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = c\cdot \cos(-bx)+ a \cdot \sin(-bx) \\
a\cdot \sin(bx)+c\cdot \cos(bx) = c\cdot \cos(bx) - a \cdot \sin(bx) \\
a\cdot \sin(bx) = -a \cdot \sin(bx) \\
2\cdot \sin(bx) = 0 \\
\sin(bx)=0$

Comment: Use \sin and \cos to produce the nice looking $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead of the ugly looking $sin$ and $cos$. For the sign function, you can use \operatorname{sgn} to get $\operatorname{sgn}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$In the Frequency $C$ section:

Firstly, $A\sqrt{1-\left(cA^{-1}\right)^2}$ is not simply $\sqrt{A^2-c^2}$, because your chosen $A$ may be negative. Instead,

$$\begin{align*}
A\sqrt{1-\left(cA^{-1}\right)^2}
&= \sgn(A) \sqrt{A^2}\sqrt{1-\left(cA^{-1}\right)^2}\\
&= \sgn(A) \sqrt{A^2-c^2}\\
&= \left[\sgn\left(a^2+c^2\right)\sgn\left(c\right)\sgn\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac ac\right)^2}\right)\right] \sqrt{A^2-c^2}\\
&= \sgn\left(c\right) \sqrt{A^2-c^2}
\end{align*}$$

Then a few equal signs later, $\sqrt{\frac{\left(a^2+c^2\right)^2}{a^2+c^2}-c^2}$ is also not simply $a$, because $a$ may be negative. Instead,

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{\left(a^2+c^2\right)^2}{a^2+c^2}-c^2} &= \sqrt{\left(a^2+c^2\right)-c^2}\\
&= \sqrt{a^2}\\
&= |a|\\
&= \sgn (a)\cdot a
\end{align*}$$

Then the overall $A\sin(B+Cx)$ should be:

$$\begin{align*}
A\sin (B+Cx) &= c\cos(Cx) + \sgn(c) \sqrt{A^2-c^2}\cdot\sin(Cx)\\
&= c\cos (Cx) + \sgn(c)\sqrt{\frac{\left(a^2+c^2\right)^2}{a^2+c^2}-c^2}\cdot \sin(Cx)\\
&= c\cos(Cx) + \sgn(c)\sgn(a)a\sin(Cx)\\
&= c\cos\left[\sgn(a)\sgn(c)Cx\right]+a\sin\left[\sgn(a)\sgn(c)Cx\right]
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a\sin (bx)+c\cos(bx)=A\sin(B+Cx)$$

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}\sin(bx)+\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(bx)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}\sin(B+Cx)$$

Let $\tan (\theta_0)=c/a$.

Then $$\sin(\theta_0)\cos(bx)+\cos(\theta_0)\sin(bx)=\sin(bx+\theta_0)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}\sin(B+Cx)$$

So $A=\sqrt{a^2+c^2}, B=\arctan(c/a), C=b$.

Comment: I just ploted this, and you need to multiply your $A$ by $\operatorname{sgn}(a)$, otherwise it doesn't work when a is negative.

Answer (score 1):

If this has to be an identity, using Taylor series around $x=0$, you just need to solve for $(A,B,C)$
$$A \sin(B)=c \tag 1$$
$$A C \cos(B)=a b\tag 2$$
$$A C^2 \sin(B)= b^2 c \tag 3$$
Using $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives $C^2=b^2$ which has two solutions. Depending on the sign of $b$, just solve/